# How does jersey handles @pathparam injection internally?

Tags: java, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I have been using jersey framework for developing restful web service in java for about a month now but somehow one thing i cant seem to comprehend is how does jersey handles @pathparam injection in resource methods,I know that hk2 is used under the hood for dependency injection in jersey and i know that abstract binder and factories are used for custom injection but i want some clear docs referring to the process of how does @Pathparam get injected into the method i.e step by step breakdown of some sort. I also came across the term ValueFactoryProvider while searching but all of it was pretty vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at `PathParamValueParamProvider` in the jersey-server artifact. This seems to where the magic happens together with implementations of `MultivaluedParameterExtractor`.
 They are internal classes so I could not easily find any good javadoc. Looking at the sourcecode though, there are good comments which could help you break it down.